# JQuery UI Autocomplete - Have the menu open when user clicks in the text box

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

I'm using this [JQuery autocomplete widget](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete).

How can I make it automatically open the menu when the user clicks in the text box?  I want the user to see all the options.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need to trigger the `search` event manually and set the `minLength` option on the widget to zero:

```
$("input").autocomplete({
    minLength: 0,
    /* other options */
}).on("focus", function () {
    $(this).autocomplete("search", "");
});
```

**Working example:** http://jsfiddle.net/9JmVu/

Comment: I couldn't get this to work in the version we are using however, replacing "on" with: 

.focus(function(){$(this).autocomplete("search", "")});

worked great.

Comment: You may be using an earlier version of jQuery.

Comment: Is this possible without calling the `search` event?

Comment: @soham.m17: I don't think so. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Actually, the whole list is available at the `ul` that was created and I want to go with the available data and don't want to refresh it.

Answer (score 2):

I think I got it actually.  If you set minLength to 0, and then trigger a search for "", it opens the menu.

```
      $(inputSelector).autocomplete(
              {
                  source: this.validConstructCodes,
                  minLength: 0,
                  autoFocus: true,
                  autoSelect: true
              });
      $(inputSelector).focus(function(event) {
        $(this).autocomplete( "search" , "" );
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

As explained from Andrew you need to trigger the event.

But once you got the result from an ajax request, it's better to show the results again instead of asking the server again. The minLength value is independent, could be 2 as recommended on server requests.

```
$("input").autocomplete({
    minLength: 2,
    /* your options */
}).on("focus", function () {
    /* the element with the search results */
    var uid = $("#ui-id-"+$(this).autocomplete("instance").uuid);

    if(uid.html().length == 0) {
        /* same as $(this).autocomplete("search", this.value); */
        $(this).keydown();
    }
    else {
        uid.show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Slight change of @amalesh answer to work with jQuery Autocomplete v1.8.
I added +1 to the uuid because it starts from 0 but the id is set to 1.

```
$("input").autocomplete({
        minLength: 2,
        /* your options */
}).on("focus", function () {
        /* the element with the search results */
        //
        let uid = $("#ui-id-" + ($(this).autocomplete("instance").uuid + 1));
        if(uid.html().length === 0) {
            /* same as $(this).autocomplete("search", this.value); */
            $(this).keydown();
        }
        else {
            uid.show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: This would add a 1 at the end of the UUID. Not sure what that would accomplish

Comment: Exactly. In the autocomplete source code you can see that the id is assigned like #ui-id+(++uuid) where uuid is 0. So it increments one before assignment. If you just take the value then it will look for #ui-id-0 which, at least in my case, is nowhere to be found.