# Reopening jQueryUI autocomplete search box on focus if it has a search term in it

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

If I type a search into the box the autocomplete menu appears and when it looses focus it disappears as expected. The search term is left in the box but when it regains focus the autocomplete menu doesn't reappear.

How can I make the autocomplete menu reappear if there is a search term currently in the search box?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery UI Autocomplete - Have the menu open when user clicks in the text box](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8401734/jquery-ui-autocomplete-have-the-menu-open-when-user-clicks-in-the-text-box). Although this one *is* slightly different in that it uses `this.value` and not empty string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Execute the search again (using the [`search`](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#method-search) method on autocomplete) with the current value of the input when `focus` occurs:

```
$("input").autocomplete({
    /* options... */
}).focus(function () {
    $(this).autocomplete("search", this.value);
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/J5rVP/31/